# User Agent navegador

Tags: scrapy

Estoy intentando entrar con una araña scrapy en la pagina www.coches.net, no me deja y me han recomendado utilizar el agente usuario de google bot ¿Alguien puede decirme donde conseguir la denominación exacta y/o actualizada.
Gracias por anticipado

Answer (score 0):

en tu archivo `setting.py` añade la siguiente variable:
`USER_AGENT = 'Aquí va el User-Agent que quieras'`.